# I want to click an element using css selectors and open it in a new browser window then send it behind the existing browser window using Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner in Jquery or Javascript so, this is what should be happening.

1. In a website(not mine nor have a control), I visited I want to click this html element below.

**HTML**

```
<a class="_ng0lj" href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow me noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">www.example.com</a>
```

2. This link should be opened in a new tab.
3. When the tab pops-up, will send that window BEHIND the rest of the browser windows.

**Where I am:**
For now, I am currently in the process of trying to get the link from the class=_ng0lj and store it on a var so that I could use this for the next function.

**NEXT:** 
Execute a function to open this var with the link to a new browser window and send it to the rest of the browser windows.

**Jquery**

```
$('div a._ng0lj').click(function(){});
```

I did open the link but not on the new window plus I want to get the link for the other purposes that's why I want to know how I could grab the link and store it in a var.

Hope this makes any sense.

Comment: Ahm... Semi unrelated with your question... why send a popup behind? (sounds a bit shady - or maybe I read the question wrong?)

Comment: @zozo I apologise that this confuses you. Yes, you got it right, I want to send the new browser window behind the browser window where the click event happens. For some reason, I want to do something with it in that window after it was opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the link : `$('a._ng0lf').attr('href')`

To open a window in background :

```
var otherWindow = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
otherWindow.blur();
window.focus();
otherWindow.location.href = href;
```

Comment: Thanks @ludovic, but can this be more specific? appreciated.